# ALTER TABLE mudando nome coluna

Tags: sql, tabela-banco-de-dados, dml

Ao usar `ALTER TABLE` para modificar o nome da coluna em uma tabela, precisamos definir o tipo dos dados novamente:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela CHANGE COLUMN nome_antigo novo_nome tipo_dados;
```

Caso o tipo de dado não seja definido, aparece um *syntax error*. Toda vez que formos alterar o nome de uma coluna também é necessário declarar o tipo de dado ou existe outra forma mais simples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade para trocar apenas o nome o correto é :

```
ALTER TABLE tabela RENAME COLUMN nome_antigo TO novo_nome;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/Rename.sql).